# PPT:objective-c to Retrieve Current Slide title

Tags: macos, powerpoint

I try to retrieve current slide title when set PPT automatic turn the page in Mac, but I don't know how to do it,please help me.

Comment: I can write a vbs Macro to get the title, but that is not good idea. I  remember I can get title with WINDOW OS by register a COM component,then my code can get title when ppt is turned the page.